# Conflict archiving my Cordova App on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

When I try to make an archive for iOS using xCode for my Cordova App, I have 2 errors message :

1. TheApp has conflicting provisioning settings. TheApp is automatically signed, but code signing identity iPhone Developer: mail@mail.com (NUMBER) has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
2. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

I don't understand what I have to do...

Comment: Please be more specific as to how you are building the app. Are you using `cordova build ios ...` or Xcode? Have you configured `build.json` appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

In the "build settings" , try to find Code signing section, in this you have some parts as code signing identity 
In the part for developer set this to iPhone Developer , not the one your name mentioned in .

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Cordova CLI you should do the signing with the CLI too.

But if you want to use Xcode, you have to open the `build-release.xcconfig` file located at Resources/config and remove the two lines with `iPhone Distribution` value